# After a user is redirected to a page in my quick app from a card, how can my app directly take them back to the card?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

In my Huawei quick app, when  I have opened page A in a quick app, and then taps a card or other media to proceed to page B, tapping the back button in the upper left corner redirects them to page A first. But it is expected to be redirected directly to the card after tapping the back button. How does it occur?

Comment: Perhaps there's something wrong with the upper left corner?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the default startup mode **standard**, which the page adopts. In this mode, every new page started by the user will be cached in the page stack, so a page that is opened for multiple times will be cached repeatedly. As a result, the user can only close one page at a time. To solve this problem, you are advised to set the startup mode of page B to **clearTask** using the dynamic declaration when the user taps a card to go to a quick app. In this case, page A closes when page B opens, meaning only page B exists in the page stack. When the user taps the back button, they will directly exit the quick app.

[image]

You can use the following sample code for redirecting a user from a card to a quick app using deep links:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Quick app test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="hwfastapp://com.huawei.hello1/Test?___PARAM_LAUNCH_FLAG___=clearTask">Open through hwfastapp.</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="hap://app/com.huawei.hello1/Test?___PARAM_LAUNCH_FLAG___=clearTask">Open through hap.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Target page of the quick app to which the card is redirected (There is always only one page based on the number of current page stacks.)

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <text>___PARAM_LAUNCH_FLAG___=</text>
    <text>{{taskflag}}</text>
    <text>Number of current page stacks.</text>
    <text>{{length}}</text>
  </div>
</template>
 
<style>
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
 
  text {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
</style>
 
<script>
import router from '@system.router';
  export default {
    data: {
      // The default is the local app internal image
      photoUri: '/Common/logo.png',
      taskflag:'',
      PARAM_LAUNCH_FLAG:'',
      length:''
    },
 
    onInit() {
      this.$page.setTitleBar({ text: 'deepLink' })
      var that=this;
      that.taskflag=this.PARAM_LAUNCH_FLAG;
      // Call the getPages method.
      let pages = router.getPages()
// The obtained value is a JSON array. Therefore, the value cannot be displayed directly. You can use the following method to display the value:
      console.log("tag", this.printJSONArray(router.getPages()));
      that.length= router.getLength();
      console.log("pages' length = "+that.length);
    },
 
    printJSONArray(array) {
      let result = ""
      const suffix = ", "
      Array.isArray(array) && array.forEach((element, index) => {
        result = result + JSON.stringify(element) + (index === array.length-1 ? "" : ", ")
        })
      return result
    }
  }
</script>
```

The page launch mode can be configured in two modes: static declaration in the manifest file and dynamic parameter pass declaration, of which the latter is recommended. The static declaration mode applies to scenarios with fixed settings which cannot be flexibly adjusted.

For more details,you can refer to this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/quickApp-References/quickapp-api-router#push?ha_source=hms1) and [deep link documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/quickApp-Guides/quickapp-develop-deeplink?ha_source=hms1).